# How to get Array each name and show in Info Box

Tags: laravel

Good Evening...
I am a self-learner and do projects for the home.
I am trying to show the info-box based on nos of Society name and show each society name in the same.
I was able to get the Nos of info-box but stuck on how to get the Name for each info-box.

Here is my blade file.

```
<div class="row">
@foreach ($getsocietyname as $item)
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header">
            <strong>Get Society Name </strong>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">Total Customer</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Active Customer</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

Controller File

```
$getsocietyname = DB::table('Customer')->select(DB::raw('society'))
                    ->groupBy('society')->get(); // get society name


$getallcustomerdatafortable = Customer::select(DB::raw('status,society'))
                                ->where('status','=','active')->get();
```

Ref. Images

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confusing but maybe this simple ....

```
<strong>{{ $item['society'] }}</strong>
```

Edit as per comment

```
<strong>{{ $item->society }}</strong>
```

Comment: Not Working. Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: <strong>{{ $item->society }}</strong> ..... This is Working.... Thank U